# How to assign a second parameter value on ng-change in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have simple drop-down bind with angular model

```
<select                                               
    ng-model="user.Id"
    ng-options="convertToInt(c.Id) as c.Name for c in users"
    ng-change="changeItem(user.Id)"
     >
    <option ng-selected="c.Id == user.Id" value="{{c.Name}}"></option>
</select>
```

and in controller

```
$scope.changeItem = function(item){
   //userid
}
```

How can I get User name from the select box, ie return c.Name?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about

```
 <selectng-model="user"
    ng-options="item as item.name for item in users  track by item.id"
    ng-change="onChange()">
     </select>

$scope.onChange = function(){
       console.log($scope.user);
    };
```

[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/620ov7dx/1/)

Comment: What about on update? ie $scope.user has value? in that case selected value is not setting in dropdown

Answer (score 2):

Pass the whole user object

```
 ng-change="changeItem(c)"
```

and then,

```
$scope.changeItem = function(item){
  console.log(item.name);
}
```

Comment: what is the issue

Comment: it should return an object

Comment: name = "", and Id has value.

Comment: sorry it should be ng-change="changeItem(c)"

Comment: No luck, this time getting undefined.

Comment: can you create jsfiddle

Comment: Ok. I will try.

Answer (score 2):

Pass the Alice object

```
ng-change="changeItem(c)"
```

and then,

```
$scope.changeItem = function(user){
  console.log(user.name);
}
```

Comment: No , it getting undefined

Comment: **Please try this code**  : `<select ng-model="user" ng-options="c.Name for c in users" ng-change="changeItem(user)">
  <option ng-selected="c.Id == user.Id" value="{{c.Name}}"></option>
</select>`

Answer (score 0):

Select the entire object to a `selectedUser` and you can get what ever you want out of the object.

```html
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="HomeCtrl as vm">
  <select ng-options="user as user.name for user in vm.users" ng-model="vm.selectedUser"></select>
  
  <p>Selected user: {{vm.selectedUser.name}}</p>
</div>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
angular.module('myApp', [])
.controller('HomeCtrl', function() {
  let vm = this;
  vm.users = [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: 'John',
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: 'Joe',
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      name: 'Jim',
    },
  ];
  
  vm.userId = 2;
  vm.selectedUser = vm.users.find(u => u.id === vm.userId);
});
</script>
```